# Can I open a file using the index shown by ":scriptnames"?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, multiple-files

I am wondering how to open a file or load it into a buffer using the index shown by `:scriptnames`?

```
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

*e.g.*, the 25th?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Vim [8.1.553](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0553), you can simply supply a count to the scriptnames command to have it edited. So in your case, you can simply use:

```
 :25scriptnames
```

or

```
 :scriptnames 25
```

to edit the zipPlugin.vim

Answer (score 4):

Another option is the `Scriptnames` command in Tim Pope's vim-scriptease plugin.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease

The script names are loaded into a quickfix list.  Hitting return opens the script name under the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to load the output of `:scriptnames` in a buffer like so:

```
:call setline('.', split(execute('scriptnames'), '\n'))
```

This will give you this in the current buffer:

```
  1: ~/.vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
  [..]
```

And you can then use `gf` to go to the files.

---

I find this pattern in general useful enough that I have a little command for it:

```
comm! -complete=command -nargs=+ Load call call(
            \ (len(filter(getline(1, '$'), {_, v -> len(v) > 0})) == 0 ? 'setline' : 'append'),
            \ ['.', split(execute(join([<f-args>], ' ')), '\n')])
```

You can then just type `:Load scriptnames`.

You can modify it to automatically create a new (scratch) buffer or split or whatnot (although you can use `:new | Load scriptnames`).