# Write command history to buffer

Tags: command-history

I'd like to insert the output from `:history` into the current buffer or alternatively write it to file. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think the answer at https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37539/18609 does exactly what you want here. In your case, `:put =execute('history')`

Comment: Try the following: `exe ":redir > vim_history.txt|:sil history |redir END"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little `Load` command in my vimrc that will insert the output of any command in the buffer:

```
command -complete=command -nargs=+ Load call(
    \ (getline(1, '$')->filter((_, v) => len(v) > 0)->len() == 0 ? 'setline' : 'append'),
    \ ['.', execute(<q-args>)->split('\n')])
```

You can then use `:Load history` (or any other command).

---

This command looks a bit arcane; let's use a simpler version of the same:

```
command -complete=command -nargs=+ Load append('.', execute(<q-args>)->split('\n'))
```

It calls `execute()` on `<q-args>`, which expands to the command arguments (`history` in `:Load history`) with quotes, it then splits this on newlines with `->split('\n')`. `append()` adds lines to the buffer after the current line (indicated by `.`).

This works well except for a small issue: if the buffer is currently empty you will end with an empty line at the top, because it "appends after the current line". This is what you want if there's already text in your buffer, but not when it's empty.

So the first line in that command:

```
(getline(1, '$')->filter((_, v) => len(v) > 0)->len() == 0 ? 'setline' : 'append')
```

Finds the appropriate command to use: `getline(1, '$')` gets all lines in the buffer, the `filter` removes empty lines, and if the number of lines if `0` it uses `setline()`, which sets the current line, overriding any text. Otherwise it will use `append()`.

It's kind of a minor thing, but makes it a little bit nicer :-)

---

There are simpler ways to do the same, such as `:put =execute('history')` as filbranden mentioned in the commands, but it's not as "nice" as it's quiet a bit more typing and it leaves a blank line on top.

Comment: Just a note that `=>` is from vim9 syntax

Comment: Oops, I thought there wasn't any Vim9 syntax in there @D.BenKnoble, but I missed that one. I just remembered I [posted that same command before](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31885/51), so people can use that version for older Vims or Neovim.

Answer (score 1):

There is always more than one way to do something but you can simply open command-line window (e.g. by pressing `q:` in Normal) and then copy/paste its contents as usual.